# Line breaks </ br> changing to <!-- br--> when switching between HTML and Visual tab!

Tags: visual-editor, code

I'm a code newbie and I was just making a wordpress post and instead of using the correct line break code of `<br />` I used `</ br>` in the VISUAL editor. When I switched to the HTML editor and back to the VISUAL editor, to my surprise the line break code was still there. But it had changed from `</ br>` to `<!-- br-->`

Should I just use that `<!-- br-->` code now instead of `</ br>` or `</ br>`? If it's okay, I would like to because I like switching between visual and html tabs. This allows me to do that with the line break code to disappear. So should i use that `<!-- br-->`? I don't want it to break my theme later on if i'm using the wrong code.

Answer (score 1):

This `<!-- br-->` does not do anything, most probably WP nulled it because it was broken, so you should use `<br />` , in HTML mode.

Comment: Oh i just looked at the page source it says,  

    <p><!-- br--><br />
<!-- br--><br />
<!-- br--><br />
<!-- br--><br />
<!-- br--><br />
<!-- br--><br />
<!-- br--><br />
<!-- br--><br />
<!-- br--></p>
<p>my text, text, text</p>

do you think i could leave it like that?

Comment: Use just `<br>` or `<br />`, `<!-- br-->` is an invalid markup, invalid = not good = useless ;) . From what I know WP can auto add <br> just by pressing the ENTER on your keyboard, and it is always hiding `<br>` and `<br />`.

Answer (score 0):

`</ br>` is invalid markup. The editor can either remove it or hide it in a comment. It does the latter, so you can fix it by hand.

For line breaks use `<br>` or `<br />`, nothing else.

Comment: Ok so the <code></ br></code> is an invalid markup but it does produce a line break though. Can I use it? I just want to because the line break doesnt disapear when i switch between tabs

Comment: Use it _for what?_